# How to collect each nodes to array with children as objects?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I would like to pick up children as objects in each row as array. How to do this?

For now I can get list of `.row` children classes:

```
require "nokogiri"
html = <<-EOS
<div id="layout-grid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">.col-md-12</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
    </div>
</div>
EOS

def jsonize_grid(element)
  rows = []
  rows << element.css('.row > div').map {|node| { col: node.attr('class') } }
  rows
end
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html).css("#layout-grid")
puts jsonize_grid(doc)
```

My desired result:

```
[{col: "col-md-12"}],[{col: "col-md-6"},{col: "col-md-6"}]
```

I would be very grateful for help.

Comment: What's the problem? the code works!

Comment: For now I have "flat" columns list that I would like to push in right row array.

Comment: Your desired result isn't a valid Ruby object or JSON string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map twice in order to get an array of array.

This should return what you want:

```
def jsonize_grid(element)
  element.css('.row').map{|row| row.css('div').map{|div| {col: div.attr('class')}} }
end

# [[{:col=>"col-md-12"}], [{:col=>"col-md-6"}, {:col=>"col-md-6"}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd go about it this way:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<div id="layout-grid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">.col-md-12</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
    </div>
</div>
EOT
```

Here's how to find the "layout-grid" block, then the embedded ".row" divs:

```
content = doc.search('#layout-grid .row').map{ |row| 
  row.search('div').map{ |div| 
    {'col' => div['class']}
  } 
}

content 
# => [[{"col"=>"col-md-12"}], [{"col"=>"col-md-6"}, {"col"=>"col-md-6"}]]
```

`'#layout-grid .row'` is the CSS selector that tells the libXML2 library to do most of the heavy work when finding the embedded divs, which translates to speed if you're processing a big HTML file.

The parameters to tags, whether they're in an XML or HTML file, can be easily accessed using `[...]`, as if the node was a Hash. That makes it less verbose and more readable to use `div['class']`.

`content` can be turned into JSON using:

```
require 'json'
puts content.to_json
# >> [[{"col":"col-md-12"}],[{"col":"col-md-6"},{"col":"col-md-6"}]]
```